# Identiying the connectors in a laser pico projector?

Tags: pcb, connector

I've opened up a Microvision Showwx pico projector (see picture).
[image]
I want to be separate out the projection display part from the PCB part and extend the connection somehow - basically disconnect the PCB from the ribbon with 3 connections and reconnect them such that there are a wires/ribbons of 10cm in between. What is the best way to do this? I'm thinking the best way is to get the connectors for the ribbon, connect them to a conversion board, solder wires into the board and do the same on the PCB side. Is this the right approach? I'm unable to identify the connectors that are present - are these QFN?

Comment: From your current photo, it's impossible to tell what connectors those are.  The photo shows the stiffeners at the back of the flex circuit, while the connectors are on the other side of it.  If you can un-mate the connectors and take pictures of male and female on both sides (better light and resolution too), then it could be possible to ID the connectors.  Another approach could be (in principle) to un-solder the contacts on the other ends of the flex and solder the extension wires there.

Answer (score 1):

[image: a better picture of those connectors]

I doubt that it would be a good idea to extend them.

What I wish I could do is find a way to convert this non-HDMI model to take HDMI input, because I want to connect it to a Raspberry Pi.  I even got an HDMI-to-VGA converter but it refuses to do 800x480, only 640x480, which is a waste of pixels.  I'm suspecting maybe J3 on this board is a digital input:

[image: back side of the top board]

because it's not in use, and it's near where the HDMI connector would be on the HDMI model, and that board has an ISL98002 chip which converts analog video to digital, outputting a 24-bit digital bus.  So that means at least one of the connectors going to the bottom board (with the Altera) must be carrying raw digital video.  They probably made a different variant of the top board with an HDMI connector there.  But I didn't do any probing around, just had a look and put it back together and made sure it still worked.

Even the main input connector has a lot of pins, so it's conceivable that it carries something more than VGA and composite inputs.

[image: overall layout]

Comment: I never got any further with this.  Did anyone else?  I finally got a "Gert" VGA board for my Raspberry Pi 3, and... guess what?  The projector is not happy with any resolution that I've tried, ouput from that board.  (Possible modes are listed [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md).) At 848x480 it shows the blue screen saying that mode is not supported (unknown mode @ 60Hz).  At 640x480 60Hz it doesn't even do that: it just keeps the splash screen that it shows on power-up.  I'm going to get a CubieTruck and see if I have any better luck.

Comment: But [this guy](https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/3j3w9l/pi_powered_portal_guns/) says he was able to drive it at the right resolution from a Raspberry Pi, with an HDMI->VGA adapter (?).  I just got mine working at 720x480 with such an adapter, although about every other second the picture jumps.  This projector is extremely picky about the VGA signal you give it.